# Proof that the space of morphisms between equivalent irreps has dimension 1.

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Schur's lemma says that for finite group representations, this space between non-equivalent irreps has dimension 0, and that the morphisms between identical irreps are homothety. Yet I forgot how to prove that the space of morphisms between equivalent irreps has dimension 1 using these two results. Could anybody give me a hint or answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho\colon G \to \mathrm{GL}(V)$ be representation and $k$ the field of scalars.

Morphisms from the representation $\rho$ to itself are linear maps $V \to V$ that commute with the action of $\rho$.  The important bit hear is that the map $V \to V$ is linear and a linear homothety is just multiplication by a scalar.  So if we define $\phi_\lambda$ by $v \mapsto \lambda v$ then $\lambda \mapsto \phi_\lambda$ gives the isomorphism between $k$ and the space of endomorphisms of the representation $\rho$.

Comment: Now I can understand the mechanism. Thanks a lot!